# Using limit() on a Select in ZF2 with SQL Server

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

**e: just realized this might have something to do with the fact that it's SQL Server. Anyone know the ZF2 equivalent to LIMIT for SQL Server?**

Hi everyone,

stuck with ZF2 as always.

I have a fetchAll() method in a class that selects rows from a certain table. Now, the method works but I can't seem to put a limit on it.

This works (and returns the rows in the proper order):

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){
        $select->order('messageId ASC');
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

but from how I understand it, limit should be fairly easy (and similar), so I did this (which does not work):

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){
        $select->limit(30);
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

It doesn't return anything now. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seemed to work!

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){
        $select->quantifier('TOP 15 ')
            ->order('id ASC');
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

which would be the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM tablename ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Zend's SQL server abstraction is nothing short of terrible. Whats the point of using an abstraction layer when you need to write SQL that is not cross platform to do simple things like limiting records.

Answer (score 6):

Using offset()

```
public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function(Select $select){
        $select
            ->limit(30)
            ->offset(10);
    });
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, use offset() to avoid use zend pagination.